# How can I decode serial data I captured as a digital waveform?

Tags: serial-port, labview

I'm trying to read data stored on an exhaust valve actuator device. To activate the readout a set of PWM pulses at a specified frequency and sequence of duty cycles has to be applied on the device's PWM-IN pin:

```
frequency 300 Hz ±5
1. Duty cycle 80 ±5 (10 periods)
2. Duty cycle 50 ±5 (10 periods)
3. Duty cycle 10 ±5 (10 periods)
```

After the last duty cycle the device transmits 95 bytes of data serially on the PWM-IN and the PWMOUT line. For data transmission, a baud rate of 9600Baud/s ±5% is used. A start and a stop bit is added to every byte, complying with an RS232 8N1 interface.

Using a NI USB-6341 I can generate the PWM pulses but I tried to read the serial data using a digital input (Change detection) without any success. I don't know if the problem is timing...rate...samples or something else.

How can I decode this digital waveform into the required bytes of data?

Serial data should be like this in Hex (95byte):

```
5555 5555 5555 5555 5555 8540 0101 0286
1001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 B0
```

Labview Code:

[image]

Serial data

[image]

Comment: What have you got working so far, and where are you having a problem? From your 'serial data' image it looks as if you are successfully generating the PWM signal and capturing the output from the device, is that correct? So your question is just about how to decode the serial data?

Comment: I want just decode the incoming serial data using NI Card. To decode data, I’m using Port P0.3.

Comment: I've edited your question quite a bit to try and reflect what I think you have done and what your problem is. If you don't agree with my changes feel free to reverse them or edit it again. Can you post an image of part of the serial data waveform you've recorded, but with a shorter timescale on the horizontal axis so we can see the individual transitions from high to low and back? I think that would help people to assess how to help you.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see from what you've posted, you can successfully activate the output of serial data from your device and you can capture this data as a digital waveform (to confirm this, please post a plot of the digital waveform where we can see each high/low transition). What you are stuck on is how to decode this waveform into the bytes of data that it represents. I can think of three ways you could go about this:

- **Decode the data by analysing the recorded waveform.** Standard serial data transmission is [encoded in a straightforward way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_serial_communication): you have a start bit, eight data bits and a stop bit. Divide up the serial data portion of the waveform into chunks representing one byte each, find whether the waveform is high or low during each of the data bits, and combine these into a byte. Unless the clock of the transmitting device is very unstable I think you should be able to do this by finding the rising edge of each start bit and looking at fixed time offsets from that point until you reach the next start bit.
- **Connect the data line directly to a serial port input.** Before spending lots of time trying to decode the data in software, I would definitely try seeing whether an ordinary serial port will recognise it! If the PWM output is at 'TTL level' i.e. 'space' is 0 volts and 'mark' is +5 volts you can use a 'TTL-USB' converter device, otherwise you may need a simple level shifting circuit to adapt the output to the right levels. You'll probably get some garbage characters due to the PWM signal before the data message but hopefully it shouldn't be hard to distinguish those from the data you want.
- **Replay the recorded waveform into a serial port input.** If receiving the serial data directly doesn't work well, i.e. if the serial receiver gets confused by the PWM signals, then you could discard the PWM section from your captured waveform and replay it out of a different digital port - I think this is supported by the USB-6341. Connect that port to a TTL-level serial input configured to receive and you should get a reliably decoded version of the data you want.

If you need more help with the software side of any of these, please ask a more specific question about the issue you're having. If you need help with the hardware interfacing it's probably best on [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at LabVIEW's software UART [examples](https://forums.ni.com/t5/Examples-and-IP-for-Software/NI-6584-Basic-Software-UART-8-and-16-Channels/ta-p/3663245?profile.language=es) but I'm afraid your hardware won't be of much use with them. You can read [here](https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/UART-Communication-with-Microcontroller-using-Labview-amp-USB/td-p/823872?profile.language=en) for more details. Unless you are doing this as a learning experience and you have a lot of time to kill, I would never even look at the idea of decoding the serial stream with your DIO card. It might sound straight forward enough but it won't be.

To be honest, I think it's quite twisted that you have to send a PWM command and the valve gives back on serial over the same link. If you already have a serial port, why not using it for communicating both ways? This looks like a homework assignment from an evil teacher.

If you want to stick to LabVIEW (I don't see why you should, I'm just assuming that's what you want), the easiest thing to do to solve your problem is to get a cheap USB-to-UART (RS232, TTL or whatever your evil valve uses) and use one of the flow control lines for the PWM. I see no reason for you not to be able to recycle your PWM LabVIEW code.

For this particular task, in my opinion, the easiest and most reliable solution would be to use any microcontroller of your liking. Even if you never used one, you can probably have a working solution within a day or two (what you have to do is nothing out of the ordinary for a microcontroller and you have tons of code and tutorials).